# problem in creating java applications in netbeans Apacha ide

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/3.0.0/exec-maven-plugin-3.0.0.pom: Unknown host No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

Comment: Your maven process cannot access the internet properly. Does that [url](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/3.0.0/exec-maven-plugin-3.0.0.pom) work in the browser?

Comment: As already mentioned: `Unknown host No such host is known` network/proxy/vpn issue....